# Unable to set variable value from Intersystem Cache Server Method

Tags: javascript, intersystems-cache, objectscript

I have came across a question when I am doing Intersystem Cache Server Page with Javascript.

Here is my Sample Code:

Case 1:

```
<script language="Javascript">
function test1(){
  var val = 0;
  #server(..Set())#;
  alert(val);
}
</script>
```

```
<script language="Cache" method="Set">
Write "val = 50;"
</script>
```

In this case, when the function `test1()` is called, the value = 0 and it is a local variable.

Case 2:

```
<script language="Javascript">
function test1(){
  #server(..Set())#;
  alert(val);
}
</script>
```

```
<script language="Cache" method="Set">
Write "val = 50;"
</script>
```

In this case, when the function `test1()` is called, the val = 50 and value is now a global variable.

So my questions are:

1. How can I successfully set a value in Case 1 through Cache Server Method?
2. Why Cache Server Method can declare a global variable in Javascript but not able to set a value to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just generate javascript code on server side this way. You can return one value from this method and get it back in Javascript.

```
<script language="Javascript">
function test1(){
  var val = #server(..Set())#;
  alert(val);
}
</script>
<script language="Cache" method="Set">
 quit 50
</script>
```

Comment: What if I want to set value for multiple Javascript variable? Does that mean that my only solution is to use delimiter on the single return value from server side and set it accordingly?

Comment: If to be honest I'm completely against plain CSP. And would not recommend it at all. And if it would be possible it would be against readability of code, how to catch where had the variable changed. So, better to use the way with the return value. And with the latest versions of Caché 2016.2+ you can return JSON and easier use on JS side.

Comment: I do agree on the readability part and JSON being the best approach to do value returning in a structural manner. Can you answer my question 2 as well so that I can put your answer as a correct answer?

Comment: you should variables in global scope because code returned from server will be executed as an anonymous function in a global scope, so variables from this function just not available there.

Comment: Understood. I tried to add your comment about question 2 into the your answer, but too bad it got rejected by the reviewer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can set a variable in this manner but it has to be in a global scope not in a function scope. If you remove `var val=0;` from your function it should work. It's better to just return values instead of using hardcoded variable names to avoid problems with scoping, duplicate naming etc.

Comment: But why must the variable be in global scope? Is it because of the way how cache compile a CSP into a html page?

Comment: No this is how JavaScript works. Code you return from server is executed in separate JS context from your function, and when JS leaves that context all local variables will be discarded. Treat it like code you have return from server is in its separate function() {} block.